# When one user function is altered, other user function doesn't return correct data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, user-defined-functions

I have two user functions, one calling the other.

First of them is defined as

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTest] (
@a INT
, @b INT
)
RETURNS @data TABLE (
    A varchar(20),
    B varchar(20),
    C varchar(20)
    )
AS BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @data
        SELECT 'A' A, 'B' B, 'C' C
   RETURN
END
```

and the other is a plain select from the first one:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTest2] (
    @a INT
    , @b INT
    , @c VARCHAR(20)
    ) RETURNS TABLE
    AS
    RETURN SELECT * FROM dbo.fnTest(@a, @b) WHERE C = @c
```

When I `ALTER` the first function, adding a new column to the result (e.g. D), the second function is still unaltered and returns only the original columns (i.e. it completely ignores column D) until it is `ALTER`ed as well.

I am pretty much clear on how to fix this (either specifying all the columns in Test2 or recreating Test2 by `ALTER` command), but the question I have is - why do I need to do that? Is there some setting that will rebuild this automatically?

For the record, the ALTER query I used is:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTest] (
    @a INT
    , @b INT
    )
RETURNS @data TABLE (
    A varchar(20),
    B varchar(20),
    C varchar(20),
    D varchar(20)
    )
AS BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @data
        SELECT 'A' A, 'B' B, 'C' C, 'D' D
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: BTW, the same behavior is seen when a view is created as `select * ...`. Adding columns to the underlying table does not add columns to the view.

Comment: It really feels like the creating or modifying a function that calls another creates a list of fields used by the first function. This field list does not appear to change until the calling function is updated. I would like to know why, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refresh metadata using [`sp_refreshsqlmodule`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754.aspx):

> Updates the metadata for the specified non-schema-bound stored
>   procedure, user-defined function, view, DML trigger, database-level
>   DDL trigger, or server-level DDL trigger in the current database.
>   Persistent metadata for these objects, such as data types of
>   parameters, can become outdated because of changes to their underlying
>   objects.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTest] (
@a INT
, @b INT
)
RETURNS @data TABLE (
    A varchar(20),
    B varchar(20),
    C varchar(20)
    )
AS BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @data
        SELECT 'A' A, 'B' B, 'C' C
   RETURN
END;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTest2] (
    @a INT
    , @b INT
    , @c VARCHAR(20)
    ) RETURNS TABLE
    AS
    RETURN SELECT * FROM dbo.fnTest(@a, @b) WHERE C = @c
    GO

    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTest] (
    @a INT
    , @b INT
    )
RETURNS @data TABLE (
    A varchar(20),
    B varchar(20),
    C varchar(20),
    D varchar(20)
    )
AS BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @data
        SELECT 'A' A, 'B' B, 'C' C, 'D' D
    RETURN
END
GO

EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule 'dbo.fnTest2';
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/538e01/1/0)**</kbd>

Or you can ue [`WITH SCHEMABINDING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx):

> **If a user-defined function is not created with the SCHEMABINDING
>   clause, changes that are made to underlying objects can affect the
>   definition of the function and produce unexpected results when it is
>   invoked.** We recommend that you implement one of the following methods
>   to ensure that the function does not become outdated because of
>   changes to its underlying objects:
>
> 1) Specify the `WITH SCHEMABINDING` clause when you are creating the function. This ensures that the objects referenced in the function
>   definition cannot be modified unless the function is also modified.
>
> 2) Execute the `sp_refreshsqlmodule` stored procedure after modifying any object that is specified in the definition of the function.

Keep in mind that `SELECT *` is not allowed when `SCHEMABINDING` is used.